# error after submit overiding registration form (FOSUserBundle) in Symfony 3 and 2.7

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm trying to overiding FOSUSerBUndle Registration form, but when I submit this form I get error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO fos_user (username, username_canonical, email, email_canonical, enabled, salt, password, last_login, locked, expired, expires_at, confirmation_token, password_requested_at, roles, credentials_expired, credentials_expire_at, sex) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, null, null, null, 1, "np04lzt9veo4ow8kc88w8ocgsc4sg4g", null, null, 0, 0, null, null, null, "a:0:{}", 0, null, "Homme"]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'username' cannot be null
```

Registration Controller:

```
namespace BISSAP\UserBundle\Controller;

use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent as FormEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\GetResponseUserEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FilterUserResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;
use BISSAP\UserBundle\Entity\User;
use BISSAP\UserBundle\Form\RegistrationType as Register;


/**
 * Controller managing the registration
 *
 * @author Thibault Duplessis <thibault.duplessis@gmail.com>
 * @author Christophe Coevoet <stof@notk.org>
 */
class RegistrationController extends Controller
{
    public function registerAction(Request $request)
    {
        /** @var $formFactory \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface */
        $formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.registration.form.factory');
        /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
        $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        /** @var $dispatcher \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface */
        $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');
        $user = $userManager->createUser();
        $user->setEnabled(true);
        $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE, $event);
        if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
            return $event->getResponse();
        }

        $form = $this->createForm(Register::Class, $user, array('allow_extra_fields' =>true));

        //$form = $formFactory->createForm();
        $form->setData($user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $ERR = $form->getErrors();


        if ($form->isValid()) {
            // dump($user);
            //         die();
            $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
            $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);
            $userManager->updateUser($user);
            if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
                $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_registration_confirmed');
                $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
            }

            $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));
            return $response;
        }
         return $this->render('BISSAPUserBundle:Registration:register.html.twig', array(
        //return $this->render('BISSAPBenevolesBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),'ERR' => $ERR
        ));
    }
    /**
     * Tell the user to check his email provider
     */
    public function checkEmailAction()
    {
        $email = $this->get('session')->get('fos_user_send_confirmation_email/email');
        $this->get('session')->remove('fos_user_send_confirmation_email/email');
        $user = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager')->findUserByEmail($email);
        if (null === $user) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('The user with email "%s" does not exist', $email));
        }
        return $this->render('FOSUserBundle:Registration:checkEmail.html.twig', array(
            'user' => $user,
        ));
    }
    /**
     * Receive the confirmation token from user email provider, login the user
     */
    public function confirmAction(Request $request, $token)
    {
        /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
        $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        $user = $userManager->findUserByConfirmationToken($token);
        if (null === $user) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('The user with confirmation token "%s" does not exist', $token));
        }
        /** @var $dispatcher \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface */
        $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');
        $user->setConfirmationToken(null);
        $user->setEnabled(true);
        $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRM, $event);
        $userManager->updateUser($user);
        if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
            $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_registration_confirmed');
            $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
        }
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRMED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));
        return $response;
    }
    /**
     * Tell the user his account is now confirmed
     */
    public function confirmedAction()
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
        }
        return $this->render('FOSUserBundle:Registration:confirmed.html.twig', array(
            'user' => $user,
            'targetUrl' => $this->getTargetUrlFromSession(),
        ));
    }
    private function getTargetUrlFromSession()
    {
        // Set the SecurityContext for Symfony <2.6
        if (interface_exists('Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface')) {
            $tokenStorage = $this->get('security.token_storage');
        } else {
            $tokenStorage = $this->get('security.context');
        }
        $key = sprintf('_security.%s.target_path', $tokenStorage->getToken()->getProviderKey());
        if ($this->get('session')->has($key)) {
            return $this->get('session')->get($key);
        }
    }
}
```

RegistrationType:

```
namespace BISSAP\UserBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ButtonType;

class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{


    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {


        $builder->add('sex', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'choices'  => array(
                'Homme' => 'Homme',
                'Femme' => 'Femme',
                'Unknow' => 'Unknow',
            ),
        ));
        $builder->add('Enregistrer', ButtonType::class, array(
                'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'registerbox__submit bc-btn',)));
    }
/*
    public function getDefaultOptions()
    {
        return array(
            'validation_groups' => array('registration', 'Default')
        );
    }
*/ 
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
            $resolver->setDefaults(
            array(
                'allow_extra_fields' => true
            )
        );  
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType';
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'app_user_registration';
    }

}
```

And when I try to dump `$user` object after submit form, I get :

```
RegistrationController.php on line 61:
User {#381 ▼
  #id: null
  +sex: "Homme"
  #username: null
  #usernameCanonical: null
  #email: null
  #emailCanonical: null
  #enabled: true
  #salt: "h5asnpkagfcos0w0kc84ksosc40cgwg"
  #password: null
  #plainPassword: null
  #lastLogin: null
  #confirmationToken: null
  #passwordRequestedAt: null
  #groups: null
  #locked: false
  #expired: false
  #expiresAt: null
  #roles: []
  #credentialsExpired: false
  #credentialsExpireAt: null
}
```

All attributs are null only sex field (choiceType::class). why ?

also I dump $event object from RegistrationController and I get this :

```
GetResponseUserEvent {#361 ▼
  -response: null
  -request: Request {#7 ▼
    +attributes: ParameterBag {#10 ▶}
    +request: ParameterBag {#8 ▼
      #parameters: array:2 [▼
        "fos_user_registration_form" => array:6 [▼
          "email" => "test2@test2.com"
          "username" => "test2"
          "plainPassword" => array:2 [▶]
          "name" => "test2"
          "firstname" => "test2"
          "Enregistrer" => ""
        ]
        "app_user_registration" => array:2 [▼
          "sex" => "Homme"
          "_token" => "KiDAgOFmHg7GdadW9zjTAo_oWgxcvurSdmxSDBfk6rg"
        ]
      ]
    }
```

in this `$event` object, we find the data from Register Form, but attributs object $user stay empty (null)!

Now, I just try this configuration on a symfony 2.7 project => I get same error.

Comment: username field is mandatory in database or Entity (it is not null field)

Comment: but, i don't know why,  `$user` object is not hydrated when i submitted the form with full fields.

Comment: Check getParent method in your Registration form.  
It should be: return 'fos_user_registration';

Comment: Also in setDefaultOptions add name of your User entity witch extends FOS user model.  Example: 'data_class' => 'Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User',

Comment: @Srdjan `fos_user_registration` it's for Symfony <2.8; and i try to add name of my User entity in setDefaultOption, but nothing change.

Comment: Did you update your configuration file with information about new FOSUserBundle registration form?  `fos_user:
    registration:
        form:
            type: UserBundle\Form\RegistrationType`

Comment: yes, configuration file is configured about FOSUseBundle registration.

Answer (score 0):

You can not get rid of "username" field but you can copy the email into it to pass the validation:

```
class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('sex', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'choices'  => array(
                    'Homme' => 'Homme',
                    'Femme' => 'Femme',
                    'Unknow' => 'Unknow',
                ),
            ))
           ->add('Enregistrer', ButtonType::class, array(
                'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'registerbox__submit bc-btn')
           ))
       ;

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $user= $event->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();

            if ($user) {
               $form->add('username', HiddenType::clsss, array(
                   'data' => $user->getEmail()
               ));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Overwrite the "register.html.twig" template and add an event listener for four email field (on change update the username field):

```
{% extends "FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block fos_user_content %}
{% include "FOSUserBundle:Registration:register_content.html.twig" %}
{% endblock fos_user_content %}

{% block javascripts %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var onEmailChange = function (e) {
        document.getElementById('fos_user_registration_form_username').value = e.currentTarget.value;
    };
    document.getElementById('fos_user_registration_form_fullname').addEventListener('change', onEmailChange);
</script>
{% endblock javascripts %}
```

Try it.